# "The input is not a valid Base-64 string" exception on login after migrating from membership to identity 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

I just upgraded my website from memberhip to asp.net identity 2.0 based on the instructions found [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity).  I created new register and login forms, and migrated my user data to the new db tables.

If I create a new user using the register.aspx form, everything works fine.  The new user is saved to the db, and I can log in with the credentials.

But if I try to log in with an existing user that I migrated, I get the following **System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.**

From Login.aspx.cs

```
protected void SignIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<User>(new ApplicationDBContext());
        var userManager = new UserManager<User>(userStore);
        var user = userManager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text);

        if (user != null)
        {
            var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            var userIdentity = userManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, userIdentity);
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            StatusText.Text = "Invalid username or password.";
            LoginStatus.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

The exception occurs on this line:

```
var user = userManager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text);
```

I set a breakpoint to see what it was bombing on, but it just got to that line in the code and stopped.

I thought it might be due to the way I migrated the password, since new users work, but I don't see anything that matches the error in the PasswordHash column for existing users.

This is what I inserted into the PasswordHash column when I migrated the users:

```
(aspnet_Membership.Password+'|'+CAST(aspnet_Membership.PasswordFormat as varchar)+'|'+aspnet_Membership.PasswordSalt)
```

I've been working this all week, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kris

Comment: Yes, your problem is indeed with password format for the migrated users - password validator does not recognise the old format. Show us your password validator class and how you register it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm learning identity as I go. Am I wrong in understanding the password validator checks to make sure the length, complexity, etc, of new passwords?  Do you mean the VerifyPassword subroutine?

Comment: ah.. sorry, I meant to say `PasswordHasher`, not validator. See the link you posted - you need to put `SQLPasswordHasher` into your project as instructed in that article - this will fix your issue.

Comment: @trailmax Oh. I do have the 'SQLPasswordHasher' class, exactly as the article instructs.

Comment: Is this applied in your `UserManager` like this: `this.PasswordHasher = new SQLPasswordHasher();`. If yes, can you step through it in debug mode and see what exactly explodes?

Comment: @trailmax Yes, it is applied as such.  When I step through login.aspx.cs, I get to `var user = userManager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text);` and I get the exception.  It never steps through to the `UserManager` code.

Comment: You should be able to step through `SQLPasswordHasher` as this is part of your project - I believe this is where the exception happens.

Comment: Also when you login with new user - can you step through `SQLPasswordHasher`?

Comment: @trailmax When I log in with a user I created since migrating to identity 2.0, I step directly from `var user = userManager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text);` to `if (user != null)`

Comment: That means your `SQLPasswordHasher` is not used in your cycle. Make sure you use the right configuration of `UserManager` and its `PasswordHasher` property is set to `SqlPasswordHasher`

Comment: Eureka! Changed `var userManager = new UserManager<User>(userStore);` to `var userManager = new UserManager();` in my Login.aspx.cs page, and everything worked, for new and old users.  Now when I set my breakpoint, it steps right into SQLPasswordHasher.  Thanks so much for your help. (this is my first question, do you answer this since you got me in the right direction?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Login.aspx.cs file, I changed

```
var userManager = new UserManager<User>(userStore);
```

to

```
var userManager = new UserManager();
```

This allowed me to login with both existing and new users by using my UserManager instead of identity's.

Thanks to trailmax for getting me in the right direction!

Comment: This worked for me. Note that with this change there's no need for this line: var userStore = new UserStore<User>(new ApplicationDBContext());. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was that your `UserManager` did not make use of special password hasher your got from the article: `SQLPasswordHasher`.

All of the constructors in `UserManager` should have `this.PasswordHasher = new SQLPasswordHasher();`

So your `UserManager` should be:

```
public UserManager()
        : base(new UserStore<User>(new ApplicationDbContext()))
{
    this.PasswordHasher = new SQLPasswordHasher();
}
```

and

```
public UserManager(IUserStore userStore) : base(userStore)
{
    this.PasswordHasher = new SQLPasswordHasher();
}
```

Without the use of `SQLPasswordHasher` you are defaulted to use standard `PasswordHasher` that comes with Identity and that does not work with your old migrated passwords - that's the error message you were getting.

Comment: Tried this, it didn't work. The problem is I was using identity's UserManager, not mine.  Once I changed the var userManager line, when I hover over var, it shows I'm using my UserManager (whereas before it was using identity.UserManager)

Comment: @kbdank71 fair enough - without looking on the whole code - it was hard to guess what exactly you have there